# Align Fieldset in bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Take a look at [this Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/3KpUQAWhmc).

I want the `Fieldset 3` to move upwards just below `Fieldset 1` and align with `Fieldset 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to wrap the forms one and three within the same container which floats next to the container with the second form. Have a look at this:

**http://www.bootply.com/10SXxmv9Xf**